# How to search for keywords in Settings?

Tags: lumia, 8.1, settings, search

I have a Nokia 635. As I'm learning the phone, I find I have to frequently use the Settings app. However, there are too many categories or entries for me to quickly locate the particular setting of interest. At other times, they are just not intuitive, so I can't find a setting at all.

For example, I can't find where phone profiles are set (the profiles icon is the one with 3 squiggly lines). When I open Settings app and attempt to Search, the phone wants to search on the web rather than in Settings. Searching the web when I'm interested in an app specific setting is pretty useless behavior (not to mention all the irrelevant results it returns).

How do I search in Settings for keywords like "profile"?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it is currently not possible to search for settings. Microsoft knows this list is getting out of hand and Joe Belfiore has hinted that the next version of Windows phone will deal with this issue.

In the meantime it is possible to pin some of the settings to the start screen using 3rd party apps or accessing them through the notification center.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit difficult. To do this you will need Windows Phone 8.1. Hit the search button and depending on your location you might get either Cortana or Bing Search. Type in the keyword you want to search for and search for it. Cortana or Bing will give the results from the web. Swipe left to the phone section and it will give you the setting or whatever you were looking for.